# increase the max character limit for the index keys in mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, nextcloud

On Nextcloud/social we have this problem:

```
 Primary index name on "oc_social_a2_cache_documts" is too long.
```

see: https://github.com/nextcloud/social/issues/850

Is there a way to increase the limit for the character length of the index?

---

Update:
The table structure is

```
REATE TABLE `oc_social_a2_cache_documts` (
  `id_prim` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prim`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

It works, If I rename the table to a shorter name with one character less: just `oc_social_a2_cache_docums`

But that is not a solution here, since it seems to have worked before in older versions I am not sure, how the problem could only occur now with the latest update???

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Comment: MariaDB Version 10.3